# Is it possible to have different javascript codes for each browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a code from the past post here which goes like:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Is there a way to make it like there's a separate .js file for safari and another one for mozilla?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can programmaticaly check what browser the user has, and then add a script tag to the head.

For example,

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = 'firefoxScript.js';
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

This is, however, generally **a bad idea**. You should not change your behavior based on the browser, because if the browser changes it can make you code very hard to maintain. It is better to use feature detection. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a good framework for this.

Alternatively, just use a framework that already fixes most of the browser compatability problems for you, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: This is a seriously unreliable way of getting reliable cross-browser support. Especially with the new HTML5 APIs that have significantly different levels of support between versions of the same browser, such as between Firefox 3.6 and 4

Comment: @Robbles I know that, and I am clearly not suggesting it. But I always answer the question directly, even if it is a bad idea, but I will clearly warn that it is a bad idea. Most of the other answers here don't actually answer the question, they just address why it is a bad thing to do.

Comment: Good point - I changed my vote, since the code does work and the warning is there. I ran into this problem just today though with differences in the File API between Firefox 3.6 and 4, so I definitely think it's important to make sure people use the right methods.

Comment: Is there a condition the same as <!--[if IE]> that is for mozilla and safari? I'm animating a gif using javascript and it goes well in safari but in mozilla it animates faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a javascript library, such as jQuery, MooTools, Dojo et all, you should, instead of sniffing the user agent (browser), detect only it's capabilities, or else you will end up with JS files for IE6, IE7, IE8 as they all have different capabilities.

For more info look into http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html and http://www.modernizr.com/

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer, this is a terrible idea, but here goes. You can do the following in jQuery, this assumes you are using jQuery, although if you are then you wouldn't need this but whatever

```
if ($.broswer.msie) $.getScript('js/ie.js')
else if ($.broswer.mozilla) $.getScript('js/firefox.js')
else if ($.broswer.opera) $.getScript('js/opera.js')
else if ($.broswer.webkit) $.getScript('js/chrome.js')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally considered to be a much better strategy to use "feature detection" rather than "browser detection" and have code that adjusts it's technique based on whether an individual feature does or doesn't exist.

This system is much more scalable over time as browsers evolve, fix bugs, add features, etc.. because it automatically adjusts based on whether a given feature or behavior is or isn't there rather than trying to keep up with all versions of all browsers.

For example, in today's most recent browser versions, pretty much everything except IE9 supports CSS3 transitions.  But older versions of lots of browsers don't support them and someday some future version of IE will support them.

If you use feature detection to see if CSS3 exists and use it if it does and use a fallback mechanism if it doesn't, then you don't have to keep track of any of these versions.  You detect if the feature is there or not.  It's that simple.  When a future version of IE supports CSS3 transitions, you won't have to update your code to take advantage - it will do so automatically.  When someone shows up on your site with a browser you haven't specifically coded for, your feature detection will probably still work even though you've never coded for that browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't need to do this anymore given that modern Javascript frameworks take care of cross-browser compatibility for use. It's better to use a jQuery or anything similar than to re-invent the wheel...

Comment: I agree — but suppose the OP has a reason.  Does this constitute an answer?

Comment: Agreed.  That's really what those libraries like jQuery attempt to solve (among other things).

Comment: I agree with @harpo. This doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @harpo: As long as the OP does not explicitly state that using a framework is not an option I would say it is OK to at least point this out.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that a responsible answer here on SO does not ONLY literally answer the question asked, but also tries to figure out what the questioner is really trying to do and can suggest better ways to accomplish the goal.  There are many questions asked here that are the wrong way to solve the problem at hand so everyone benefits if better solutions to the problem are offered even if they aren't the exact solution that was asked for.  This is also the way I teach.  Try to understand what the real issue is so you can offer solutions beyond what they even know to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

these should help:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

or use jQuery ;)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer its better to use a framework to abstact over the browser differences. In modern web design you should never test for feature support by user agent but using a libary such as modenizer (found [here](http://www.modernizr.com/)). This will give you global variables as to if certain features exist

Answer (score 0):

These are [IE Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), and they only work on Internet Explorer.
Although they're handy for providing fallbacks for this historically buggy and feature-lacking browser, this isn't really considered the best way to provide cross-browser support.

Instead, you should use feature detection to figure out what's missing from each browser and either load alternative scripts or disable extra features.

Check out [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), it has automatic tests for just about every new feature and lets you use the results in both Javascript and CSS.